# What does the M in μM-Sux stand for?

Tags: notation

I am looking at some data regarding a study around a channel-blocking agent called suxamethonium.

The histograms of the open times of the channels at varying concentrations of suxamethonium are given. However, I am having a difficult time figuring out the dosage. Here are examples of dose listing formats:

- 200 μM-Sux
- 500 μM-Sux

etc.

I understand that μ in this context is to mean micro and I believe the suffix "Sux" is supposed to stand for suxamethonium. But what is the capital "M"? I looked it up in a scientific notation table and it stands for mega. Am I supposed to infer that this is a liquid (i.e. ML)?

Comment: $\pu{M}$ is a unit, not an SI prefix, standing for *molarity*, a measure of the concentration of a chemical species in solution.

Comment: I think it's useful for future purposes to refer you to the [IUPAC Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf) and [IUPAP Red Book](http://iupap.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/A4.pdf) which contain a lot of similar (and much more) information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The capital M is simply an abbreviation or another way to denote mol/L, or moles per liter.

More specifically, the 'M' stands for the word 'molarity', which as a physical quantity is defined as:
$$\ \frac{\text{Amount of Substance of Solute}}{\text{Volume of Solution}}$$

Therefore, $\pu{200 μM}$-Sux means $200$ micromoles of suxamethonium per liter, or $\pu{0.000200 mol/L}$ [because the micro (μ) symbol denotes $10^{-6}$].

Answer (score 11):

You are right assuming that μ is a [metric prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix), and that the number denotes the concentration of suxamethonium (suxamethonium chloride, I presume). However, this is supposed to be small caps "M" (as $\rm \small M$), not capital "M" (as $\rm M$). Also note that use of the term "[molarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration)", as well as its notation $\rm \small M$, is discouraged [[1, p.27]](https://www.nist.gov/physical-measurement-laboratory/special-publication-811):

> The term molarity and the symbol $\rm \small M$ should no longer be used because they, too, are obsolete. One should use instead amount-of-substance concentration of $\ce{B}$ and such units as $\rm mol/dm^3$, $\rm kmol/m^3$, 
>   or $\rm mol/L$.

And, of course, $1\,\rm {\small M} = 1\, mol/L$.

Also, [check out the answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/49633/41328) to a similar question "[What does the unit M stand for?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49632/what-does-the-unit-m-stand-for/49633)"

#### Reference

1. [Thompson, A.; Taylor, B. N. Guide for the use of the international system of units (SI). *NIST Special Publication 811* **2008**.](https://www.nist.gov/physical-measurement-laboratory/special-publication-811)

Comment: I had never noticed that the unit is written as small caps instead of capital! :O (+1)

Comment: @LinearChristmas No one really cares, I guess, and it's easier just to type capital M (I have this sin too). However, $\rm M$ is already reserved for *Mega*, so amount concentration units ideally needs another notation. I also caught up to this recently, probably from one of the great answers by Loong :)

Comment: I’m sure you already know this, but technically, the prefix μ is not supposed to be italicised. But as far as I know it is not possible to have upright Greek characters in mhchem/MathJaX.

Comment: @orthocresol True; I updated it with the Unicode char;)

Comment: I cannot see the units recommend ed. Also I was unaware that M is a desuete "unit". So mol/l is the way. What are the others two?

Comment: @Alchimista If I understood you correctly, your web browser fails to render some MathJax code. [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMJIx.png):) I figured it might have to do with `\pu{...}` syntax, which is not properly rendered in mobile apps, so I replaced the code with the more compatible one.

Comment: @orthocresol Although a bit annoying, upright 'mu' is possible (with Unicode), for example `$\unicode[Times]{x3BC} \rm \small M$` gives $\unicode[Times]{x3BC} \rm \small M$; usage in mhchem is possible with additional `$$` surrounding the Unicode character. It comes in handy for some formulae, *e.g.* [this Loong's answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/47870/27806).